# Interpretation of mutual information

Tags: intuition, information-theory, mutual-information

Is it correct to say that the mutual information $I(X;Y)$ quantifies how well we can *discriminate* among the outcomes of $Y$ by looking at the outcomes of $X$ (or vice versa)? If yes, do you have any reference that uses this interpretation?

**Further explanation**: I am not looking for a explanation of the meaning of MI. I am interested specifically in the interpretation that I wrote above. I remember having read it somewhere, but cannot remember what the source was. This interpretation emphasizes the role of discrimination in the definition of MI. The concept of discrimination is ingrained in the definition of mutual information through the following identity: if $Y$ has only one possible outcome, then the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$ is identically zero. For my work this interpretation it is currently very important and I would like to be able to cite a source.

Answer (score 4):

The mutual information measure $I(X;Y)$ is ***nonparametric*** measure of probabilistic dependence between the variables $X$ and $Y$. As follows from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information):

"Intuitively, mutual information measures the information that $X$ and $Y$ share: It measures how much knowing one of these variables reduces uncertainty about the other. For example, if $X$  and $Y$ are independent, then knowing $X$ does not give any information about $Y$ and vice versa, so their mutual information is zero."

In general, $I(X;Y)$ is computed for $m \times 2$ grid-histograms. You can 'bin' continuously distributed variables into $m$ intervals as to create this grid.

When it comes to the degree of covariation between *a feature value distribution and a class outcome distribution*, the information gain $IG(T,a)$ is widely used. Here $T$ is the variable associated with class outcomes and $a$ the attribute value. I refer you to the definition of criteria optimized by learning algorithm ID3 (its modern successor algorithm is called C4.5). $IG(T,a)$ is different to $I(T;A)$.

$I(X;Y)$ is also defined for continuous probability density functions, but you need to know the mathematical formula for the bivariate probability density in order to calculate it. Hence, histograms are practical for continuous stochastic variables $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Careful...mutual information isn’t restricted to describing linear or even monotonic relationships.

Comment: Thanks! - I have added a comment on that in the answer text.

Comment: “Covariance” also refers to a linear relationship, and your terminology is not quite that but very close. You could drop that first paragraph (still credit Wiki) and have a correct answer. Also, your last paragraph doesn’t make sense to me. It’s nonparametric because you can shuffle the rows...huh?

Comment: See the text now. I instead use the terms probabilistic dependence.

Comment: I like the expression "probabilistic dependence". Very elegant!

Comment: But still I need an interpretation of MI that emphasizes discrimination, or that makes it clear that quantifying "probabilistic dependence" is only possible if you are dealing with at least two items. I am making the point that this concept is ingrained in the definition of MI.

Comment: Ah - you would like me to derive the mathematical relation between $IG(T;a)$ and $I(T;A)$ - and then end up with the classifier correctness obtained when using feature value $a$, something along that line.

Comment: No. I would only like to know whether the interpretation that I have posted is correct and, ideally, have a reference in which something similar is written, so that I can cite it.

Comment: @MatchMakerEE: I have been thining about it. The definition that you also use (statistical dependence) is used often. However, would not this imply that MI is maximal and not minimal when X and Y are singleton variables? The same also goes with the interpretation in terms of predictability.

Comment: How can we quantitatively use the MI number? Say, X and Y have MI of 0.07617, while MI(X, X) and MI(Y,Y) are both around 10. MI value here is calculated by the mutual information regression from sklearn.

Answer (score 1):

From a [Kaggle webpage](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ryanholbrook/mutual-information):

> The least possible mutual information between quantities is 0.0. When
> MI is zero, the quantities are independent: neither can tell you
> anything about the other. Conversely, in theory there's no upper bound
> to what MI can be. In practice though values above 2.0 or so are
> uncommon. (Mutual information is a logarithmic quantity, so it
> increases very slowly.)

So, the answer to your question is yes when MI is "high".

However, when MI is "low", it does not necessarily mean there is no possibility of discrimination at all. The same page mentions the role of fuel type in a vehicle's price. Although fuel type MI is low, it separates two classes of prices.